# Best way to design and deploy a data driven desktop application in VB.net?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, setup-deployment

I am designing a desktop application that will be driven by local data.  I am trying to determine the best way to accomplish this.  The database would contain about 10-12 tables if I use a database and I would imagine no more than 10000 records in any one table (but honestly 99% of users would not have more than 1000 records).  I am thinking about using SQL Server Compact.  Is this a good solution?  I can certainly include this in my installation, but I am just wondering if anyone knows of a better solution?  If this is the best solution, how would you suggest that I create the tables upon deployment?  Should I just run "queries" with create table statements in them from my vb application or include a database file or what?
Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Have you checked out SQL Lite? Might be what you need. In general and on average if the tables will always be the same for all users just ship the application with it pre-made. If there are always going to be the same look-up values - ship it with those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget MS-sql and try MySQL with MySQL Connector/Net. You write your programs as if you are writing for sql-server (change prefix in MYsql, that's the trick).
Mysql is easy to manage by less professional persons, easier than any Ms-sql